# Need a count of items which have specific values in three columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I need to get a count of how many records have a specific three values in three different columns. 
This is what I have so far, but it returns 0 results, which isn't correct.

```
=SUM(($K:$K="Computers")*($Q:$Q=1)*($J:$J="Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3"))
```

I need to know how many records are a computer, with the value 1, running XP.

I am aware I haven't explained this well so please ask for clarification if needed. Thank you!

Comment: have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? alternatively use `=SUMPRODUCT(($K:$K="Computers")*($Q:$Q=1)*($J:$J="Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3"))` or `COUNTIFs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($K:$K="Computers")*($Q:$Q=1)*($J:$J="Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3"))
```

Comment: How bizarre! That was the first thing I tried, but now it works... I guess I messed it up the first time!

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS($K:$K,"Computers",$Q:$Q,1,$J:$J,"Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is working fine if you press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.